# Язык C, Windows Sockets, closesocket()

Tags: c, windows, сокет

Подскажите, в каких случаях нужен вызов **closesocket()**?

Например, если возникает ошибка при подключении **connect()**, то необходимо закрыть сокет при помощи **closesocket()**, затем снова создать сокет при помощи **socket()**, и вновь вызвать **connect()**?

Или, например, произойдет ошибка при передаче **send()** или приеме **recv()**. В таком случае тоже необходимо закрыть сокет, вновь создать и вновь подключить?

Это как-то плохо выглядит.

Перечитал кучу источников, но везде пишут невнятно и поверхностно, а хотелось бы разобраться подробно. Порекомендуйте, где можно найти качественную информацию по этой теме.

Comment: Вам не понятно отличие closesocket от общего close? Или вы не понимаете для чего вообще предназначено закрытие?

Comment: вызывайте всегда, в случае, если функции передать некорректный дескриптор сокета она просто вернет код ошибки WSAENOTSOCK. Дополнительно, закрытие сокета приостанавливает асинхронно выполняющиеся операции на этом сокете с кодом ошибки WSA_OPERATION_ABORTED. Более детально https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737582(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Общий цикл работы с ресурсом выглядит так: открытие, работа, закрытие. Под ресурсом подразумевается файлы, сокеты, потоки (stream), и куча подобных вещей. Закрытие нужно чтобы освободить ресурс, потому что, открывая его, вы не даёте использовать его другим приложениям (иначе это вызвало бы конфликт, когда что то запрашивают обе программы одновременно, и не понятно кого из них слушать, а кого игнорировать, слушать обоих при этом, невозможно). Если цикл работы вашей программы подразумевает держать открытый сокет, то в вашем случае, закрытие нужно только перед завершением работы программы.

Comment: В случае ошибок send/recv следует анализировать код ошибки. В большинстве случаев ошибки фатальны и свидетельствуют о проблемах в канале связи, но иногда ошибки свидетельствую о неправильности использования сокета (например, WSAEMSGSIZE - ошибка размера буфера, сам сокет при этом остается валидным)

Comment: Для чего используется closesocket() - я понимаю, но что происходит внутри - не совсем. Просто уничтожение (со всеми необходимыми операциями) объекта ядра? Если не удалось установить соединение при помощи connect() - пересоздавать сокет нет необходимости?

Comment: Вам надо читать документацию по каждой конкретной функции. Там обычно четко расписано, что можно делать с сокетом в случае той или иной ошибки. Например для `connect`: *"If the error code returned indicates the connection attempt failed (that is, WSAECONNREFUSED, WSAENETUNREACH, WSAETIMEDOUT) the application can call connect again for the same socket."*

Comment: Где можно найти эту документацию?

Comment: На [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737625(v=vs.85).aspx)